# could not execute mysql query in right way

Tags: php, mysql

I've data in DB as

```
| id|title        | exp_level  | skill      | company   |
|---|-------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| 1 |Web Developer|  Entry     |Java, PHP   |Virtual Inc|
| 2 |App Developer|Intermediate|Android, iOS|Virtual Inc|
| 3 |App Developer|Intermediate|Ionic, React|Virtual Inc|
```

result can be seen at [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b302b/8), OK, now requirement is that if user searches for *developer* then all jobs with `title` *developer* should be returned through query, if user searches for *Entry* then all jobs with `level` *Entry* should be returned through query and so on, I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM AVAIL_JOBS WHERE title LIKE '%App Development, Social Marketing%' OR exp_level LIKE '%Entry%' OR skill LIKE '%Java%' OR company LIKE '%App Inc%'
```

the above query works well, result can be seen at [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b302b/3), but the following query

```
SELECT * FROM AVAIL_JOBS WHERE title LIKE '%App Development, DB Admin%' OR exp_level LIKE '%Entry, Advanced%' OR skill LIKE '%Java, Spring, Angular%' OR company LIKE '%Inc, Foo, Bar, Lorem%'
```

this query returns empty value, no any data, even if there is "App", "Entry", "Java" present in table but those are not found by query result can be seen at [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b302b/7).

How to make this query work with values shown above? Any tick to get those comma seprated string values compared with table data?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DB WHERE title LIKE "%developer%"`?

Comment: The question looks __legitimate__, why down vote any explanation?
__Disclaimer__  I'm not a MySQL ninja

Answer (score 1):

Change `WHERE title LIKE '%App Development, DB Admin%'` to `WHERE title LIKE '%App Development%' OR title LIKE '%DB Admin%'`. Putting commas in the `LIKE` condition does not separate the strings. I hope I got it right !

Comment: Alternatively you could do `WHERE title IN ("%App Development%", "%DB Admin%")` I'm pretty sure

Comment: That's it the problem I'm facing, I have to get those comma containing values separated and get the response

Comment: You can use `$myValue = explode(',',$myValue);` to separate them, and be able to loop through them. you can also `explode` them and use `WHERE title REGEXP 'title1|title2|title3'`

Comment: Any example please!!

Comment: Let's say you have `Entry, Advanced` in `$title`. I would replace the commas with `$title = str_replace(',','|',$title)`. After, i would remove the whitespace with `$title = trim($title, " ")`. Now my `$title` is ready to be used with `WHERE title REGEXP '$title'`